# Almost sure convergence of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, weak-convergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose $X_i$ are mutually independent random variables such that $P(X_n=n^2-1)=1-P(X_n=-1)=n^{-2}$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. Show that $E(X_n)=0$ for all n, while $n^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\rightarrow -1$ a.s. for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

i am done with proving $E(X_n)=0$ but do not have any idea about how to approach it. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, surely you can calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$...?

Comment: but i do not have any approach to start to it!

Comment: If you don't have any idea, it might be a good start to recall the definition of the expectation value and very basic rules how to calculate it.

Comment: what should be the approach for the rest stuff?

Comment: Honestly, as long as you don't know how to calculate the expectation of such a simple random variable, you don't have to start thinking about the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of the result: use the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas to show that with probability 1, $X_n = -1$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then, use that fact to show that $\overline {X_n}$ converges to $-1$ almost surely.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you OK with the first part (claiming that $X_n = -1$ for all but finitely many $n$)?

Comment: i am trying to show it

Comment: Let $A_n = \{X_n \neq 1\}$. Note that $P(A_n) = 1/n^2$; hence, $\sum P(A_n) < \infty$. From the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we conclude that $P(A_n$ infinitely often$) = 0$.

Comment: yes till here i got it

Comment: Next, pick some $\omega$ for which $X_n(\omega) \neq -1$ only finitely often. (By the result we just showed, this occurs for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$.) Consider what the fact that $X_n(\omega) = -1$ for all but finitely many terms implies for the average $\frac 1 n \sum X_n(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

For showing $E(X_n)=0$ check that $X_n=(-1)\chi_{X_n=-1}+(n^2-1)\chi_{X_n=n^2-1}$ for all $n$ and hence $E(X_n)=(-1)P(X_n=-1)+(n^2-1)P(X_n=n^2-1)=(-1)(1-\frac{1}{n^2})+(n^2-1)\frac{1}{n^2}=0$